# convert xml to excel with multiple worksheet

Tags: xml, excel, worksheet

if I export the below xml to excel 2007...i am able to get the excel sheet correctly.

```
<Workbook>
<Worksheet >
<MyXml>
    <New A="111" B="222" />
</MyXml>
<MyXml>
    <New A="111" B="222" />
</MyXml>
</Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

But I need a workbook with more than one worksheet...How do i specify the xml in this case ?

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
  <ActiveSheet>2</ActiveSheet>
 </ExcelWorkbook>
 <Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
 </Styles>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="2" ss:ExpandedRowCount="1" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">11</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">22</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
 </Worksheet>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet2">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="2" ss:ExpandedRowCount="1" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">11</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">22</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
 </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

For more help you can take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Export_to_Excel.aspx?msg=2714732#xx2714732xx).

Finally, you can manually create an excel workbook and export it to XML so that you can examine the XML's format.

Comment: Is there a documentation as to what the `x:FullColumns` and `x:FullRows` are? Can I safely omit them or are they required attributes?