# How to merge 3 csv files to one xls in different sheets via bash

Tags: excel, bash, csv

I have 3 files (name1.csv name2.csv name3.csv)
Is it possible to merge them in one template.xls file which consists of 3 sheets (name1 name2 name 3) using bash script

Before I used for single convert:

```
for f in name1.csv; do ssconvert $f ${f%.csv}.xls; done
```

But now I need to keep it all in one file.
And would be nice to configure the storage directory

Thanks in advance

Comment: I read up on the ssconvert man page, and it seems like it's not possible. But if you read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895755/convert-xml-to-excel-with-multiple-worksheet) you can see that multi-page Excel files can be created using XML, then later saved as XLSX or XLS. The XML creation can be scripted in different ways, depending on your mileage.

Comment: I do not expect a solution only via ssconvert.
There is the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49324636/multiple-csv-files-into-a-xlsx-file-but-different-sheets-using-powershell)  for PowerShell and I am looking for a solution for Bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one way, to use the csv2xlsx application [source](https://github.com/mentax/csv2xlsx)

`./csv2xlsx -o /Path/All.xlsx -s name1 -s name2 -s name3 name1.csv name2.csv name3.csv`

Where

- `name1.csv` your csv file
- `- s name1` Its how you want to name sheet in your xlsx
- `-o /Path/All.xlsx` path and name the final xlsx file